# Embedding non-edit widgets in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

Is there any way to embed a widget in a data-bound *DataGridViewCell* when it is not in editing mode?

For example, we are wanting to display an existing calendar widget in a cell.  That cell contains a comma separated list of dates.  We want to show the calendar instead of the text.

We could create a custom cell and override the *Draw* method so that it draws the calendar in the cell, but that would not handle the mouse-over tool-tip that we already have in the existing calendar widget.

[Update]
I tried TcKs's suggestion, but was not able to create a working solution.  See the comments on that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should derive your own type from [DataGridViewColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.aspx) (e.g. a *DataGridViewCalendarColumn*) and return a *DataGridViewCalendarCell* (that you have to create yourself, too) as the CellTemplate. 
A detailed description can be found in the MSDN article [Build a Custom RadioButton Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.  This isn't exactly what I was after (it still relies on overriding the Paint method rather than actually embedding a widget), but it is as close as I have been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead of drawing calendar, take a calendar control, set them the grid as parent and set them same bounds ( left, top, width, height ) as cell has.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but but I was unable to make it work.

For the sake of example I created a button.  I set the parent to the grid view, I set the bounds to the cell's ContentBounds, I even call BringToFont on the button.  Even if set the top/left to 0,0 it still does not show on the grid.